# Adding pause and resume feature in a Wordlist Generator program

Tags: python, pickle

I am creating a Wordlist for 8 character password using 13 types of characters.
My code is:

```
import itertools
import pickle
import pathlib
import time
from typing import TextIO, Tuple

path = pathlib.Path('backup1.pkl')
if path.exists():
inputfile = open("backup1.pkl", "rb")
val_comb = pickle.load(inputfile)

print( val_comb  )
time.sleep(3)

f: TextIO=open("all_pass_combo_8_(3).txt","w")

res = itertools.product('abcdefghjklm', repeat=8) .
for i in res:
        print( val_comb  )
        f.write(val_comb)
        val_comb = (''.join(i) + "\n")
        output = open("backup1.pkl", 'wb')
        pickle.dump(val_comb, output)

output.close()
inputfile.close()
f.close()
```

So, it will take several hours for me to complete the execution of the code. But, the problem is I can't keep my computer turned on for this long. And if I close/interrupt the process at any instance, I'll have the combinations saved till that instance only and then, whenever I'll try to run the execution again it will start from its very initial state.

Some seniors told me to get my desired job done using "`pickle()`" and provided me the official link of the "`pickle()` Project Description". I read the article and jumped to YouTube for further help. Then I tried to edit my code in the format that you may see above, but I failed to perform the thing I was willing to do.

So, exactly what I want to do is:
I will run my program. It will run and generate a wordlist. Now, I have to shutdown my PC. So, I'll have to terminate the execution. Now, I want to preserve (or pickle) my progress in the process and when I start the execution of the program again, then it should resume from the same stage where I had left it; e.g. If I had terminated it on `'aaaafhgj'`. Then, it should start joining permutations and combination right from `'aaaafhgk'` and it should not repeat `'aaaaaaaa'` and so on, again. But my code is doing the same which I don't want to be done.

Answer (score 1):

To save the progress you could instead put a 'pause' inside the script itself, then save to a file.

**An example of the use of pickle**

```
import time
import pickle
import os

save_file = "save_file.tmp"

if os.path.exists(save_file):
    with open(save_file, "rb") as in_file:
        try:
            my_array = pickle.loads(in_file.read()) # reload the last operation
        except Exception:
            my_array = []
else:
    my_array = []

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        my_array.append("next") # here you can do what you want replace this part
    except KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit:
        print my_array
        with open(save_file, "wb") as out_file:
            out_file.write(pickle.dumps(my_array))
        input()
```

Hope that could help you, and it's clear is not easy to do that ;)

Comment: Sir, I am afraid, I was unable to understand that clearly (maybe due to my ignorance in the field). But, as you are saying, this edit in my code will help me to 'pause' and 'save' my progress in a file. I could not understand that how will I resume the process ahead, right from the saved progress. It will be so so so great of you, if you please edit my code and post it here. I'll always be greatful to you. @C.med

Comment: In fact, by using this method your script will interrupt your ctrl+c and will ask you to press enter to kill the process, by using that (the last part of the script) it will open the save_file and store your last change. the first part of this script check if the save_file was empty or not to update `my_array`. You could replace it but the stored object in your script.